# Why can‘t I read the input text file?

Tags: string, file, pointers, scanf, fopen

I try to read the name of a file using scanf but failed.
I am very bad at pointers and could not find the problem.
Is there a problem with the pointer to the array of string?
Here is my code:

```
int* Read_file(char* str[])
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(str[1], "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot open\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    int rows = 0;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        if(fgetc(fp) == '\n')
        {
            rows ++;
        }
    }
    rows ++;
    int* keys = (int*)malloc(3 * rows * sizeof(int));
    fseek(fp, 0L, 0);
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < rows;i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 3;j ++)
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%d", &keys[(3 * i) + j]);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return keys;
}
int main()
{
    char* str[20];
    printf("Build_tree ");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    int* keys = Read_file(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when you execute it?

Comment: I tried to print the numbers in keys(not shown in the code above), but nothing showed up. I know for sure that the txt file I typed in the command line was not empty, and there are 9 numbers in it.

Comment: Could you please attach the file contents

Comment: 1 2 3
2 4 5
3 6 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the thing is:

You need a char array to store a string(file-name). So you should use a `char` array. Instead, you were using an array of char pointers.

An array is actually a series of memory blocks. The name of the array represents a pointer to the first element of the array(in this case the first `char` variable).

While reading a string, `scanf` needs a location to store it. So you need to give it the address of the first `char` variable of your `char` array, which is available in your `char` array itself. So you have to pass `str` only to `scanf`. In the case of normal `int`,`float`, and such fundamental data types, their names represent memory blocks and not pointers to memory blocks, and hence you had to use a `&`.

Then for `fopen`, `fopen` expects a `char*`(which points to the first character of the char array stoing the filename) and you have to provide it with a `char*` . So you should pass `str`.

I think your code should go like

```
int* Read_file(char str[])
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(str, "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot open\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    int rows = 0;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        if(fgetc(fp) == '\n')
        {
            rows ++;
        }
    }
    rows ++;
    int* keys = (int*)malloc(3 * rows * sizeof(int));
    fseek(fp, 0L, 0);
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < rows;i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 3;j ++)
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%d", &keys[(3 * i) + j]);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return keys;
}
int main()
{
    char str[20];
    printf("Build_tree ");
    scanf("%s",str);
    int* keys = Read_file(str);

    //Whatever you want to do with the keys

    return 0;
}
```

Comment for any queries.

Comment: Hey, I corrected an error. Changed `char* str[]` in the `Read_file` definition header to `char str[]`.

Comment: Could you post your whole code with the file in the question.

Comment: How are you printing keys by the way?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change a line of code. Your code works fine now. Thanks very much!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it and marking it as the correct answer.